# Ruby/Rails Iterate through array and save to db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to put each string from @enc into each field of column_name as a value

```
@enc=["hUt7ocoih//kFpgEizBowBAdxqqbGV1jkKVipVJwJnPGoPtTN16ZAJvW9tsi\n3inn\n", "wGNyaoEZ09jSg+/IclWFGAXzwz5lXLxJTUKqCFIiOy3ZXRgdwFUsNf/75R2V\nZm83\n", "MPq3KSzDzLvTeYh+h00HD+5FAgKoNksykJhzROVZWbIJ36WNoBgkSoicJ5wx\nog0g\n"]


Model.all.each do |row|
encrypted = @enc.map { |i| i}
row.column_name = encrypted
row.save!
end
```

My code puts all strings from array @enc into a single field? 
I do not want that.

Help

Comment: `@enc.map { |i| i }` is the same as `@enc`. And do you mean you want one record with a column name for each element of `@enc`? Or do you want one column name for each record and each record contains one element of `@enc`?

Comment: I don't get it, do you have 3 models that you want to put a string from @enc into?

Comment: just one model one column and each field is populated with each string from array

Comment: @lurker I want  column name for each record and each record contains one element of array@enc

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
@enc.each do |str|
  m = Model.new
  m.column_name = str
  m.save
end
```

Comment: getting ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: column_name. How can I overide that?

Comment: @user3566065 what version of Rails are you running?

Comment: I have updated my answer to work around mass assignment in all versions of rails... but I suggest you try and understand what mass assignment is and why we protect against it. (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695)

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default won't allow mass assignment. You have to whitelist parameters you want permitted. Have you tried doing something like the following?

```
@enc.each do |s|
   cparams = create_params 
   cparams[:column_name] = s
   Model.create(cparams)
end


def create_params
   params.permit(:column_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the column names you are saving to. By setting each column separately you can also avoid mass-assignment errors:

```
@enc=["hUt7ocoih//kFpgEizBowBAdxqqbGV1jkKVipVJwJnPGoPtTN16ZAJvW9tsi\n3inn\n", "wGNyaoEZ09jSg+/IclWFGAXzwz5lXLxJTUKqCFIiOy3ZXRgdwFUsNf/75R2V\nZm83\n", "MPq3KSzDzLvTeYh+h00HD+5FAgKoNksykJhzROVZWbIJ36WNoBgkSoicJ5wx\nog0g\n"]

model = Widget.new
column_names = [:column1, :column2, :column3]

@enc.each_with_index do |s, i|
  model[column_names[i]] = s
end

model.save
```